# Adding shared primary key and a primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables named Invoice and Delivery

**Invoice**

```
invoiceId(PK)
```

**Delivery**

```
deliveryId(PK)
invoice_invoiceId(PK,FK)
```

These are my classes written in java

***Invoice =>***

```
@Entity(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @Id      
    @OneToOne(fetch =FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "invoice")
    private Delivery delivery;
}
```

and getters setters related to it

***Delivery =>***

```
public class Delivery{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int deliveryId;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_invoiceId",unique = true)
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

This throws me an *java.lang.NullPointerException* in place where I create a session factory coz I have included 2 @Id annotations in Delivery class.

My question is how can I make deliveryId a PK and invoice(invoice_invoiceId) a shared primary key in the same table?

Comment: did you try `@EmbeddedId` or `IdClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it by using a composite key

**This is my composite key class =>**

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeId implements Serializable{
    @Column(unique = true)
    private int deliveryId;
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoiceId",unique = true)
    private Invoice invoiceId;
    //hashcode and equals methods
}
```

**Invoice class =>**

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    private int invoiceId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "compositeId.invoiceId")
    private Delivery deliveryId;
}
```

**Delivery class =>**

```
@Entity
public class Delivery {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeId compositeId;
}
```

So the delivery table will have it's own PK and invoiceId as a shared PK

Let's say we're adding another shared pk to this Delivery table. So we need to add that too to the CompositeId class.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a "derived identity"; but having `invoice_invoiceId` be part of the `Delivery` primary key seems a bit odd.... Maybe you can try something like this:

Add an `@IdClass` for `Delivery` needs like this:

```
public class DeliveryId implements Serializable {
    private int deliveryId; // matches the name of the attribute
    private int invoice;  // matches name of attribute and type of User PK
    ...
}
```

Then specify `Delivery`'s `@IdClass` like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(DeliveryId.class)
public class Delivery {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int deliveryId;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_invoiceId", unique = true)
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

And `Invoice.delivery` needs to specify a `@MapsId` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    private int invoiceId;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice")
    private Delivery delivery;
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.